# Assigned Access + domain = black screen after restart

Tags: windows-10-v1607

I have configured a Windows 10 computer for Assigned Access for a local user called USER to run the Windows Camera app.  All of this works great - when USER logs in the Camera app is the only thing that USER can access.  If I restart the workstation then USER auto-logs in and the camera app starts up as expected.

If I add this computer to a domain then something breaks.  After a restart all I see is a black screen.  I am pretty sure there is a hidden login dialog box because on the black screen I can enter USER's password, press enter, and Assigned Access starts the Camera app as it is supposed to.

Some other relevant details -

After adding the computer to the domain I re-established assigned access:

```
Set-AssignedAccess -AppUserModelId Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App -UserName USER
```

I have verified the following registry keys under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

- AutoAdminLogon - 1
- DefaultUserName - USER
- DefaultPassword - password

I am running Windows 10 Anniversary edition with the latest updates installed.

Any suggestions?